# How to do OR statements and handling the errors with joi middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, joi

Today I found a very interesting middleware to use for validation of the body via HTTP request. I am talking about Joi. However I need to make an OR statement in order to validate one field.

My code:

```
const { celebrate, Joi } = require('celebrate');
const joiObjectId = require('joi-objectid');
const constants = require('../../constants.js');

Joi.objectId = joiObjectId(Joi);

const validateBodySchema = celebrate({
  body: Joi.object().keys({
    name: Joi.string()
      .required()
      //.error(new Error('Name is a required field!'))
      .min(constants.MIN_CHAR_NAME)
      .max(constants.MAX_CHAR_NAME),
  
    address: Joi.string()
      .required()
      //.uri() -> This doesn't work because it checks whether the string is an uri valid AND an ip address. I need an OR here
      //.ip(),
    type: Joi.string()
      .required(),
  })
});

module.exports =  validateBodySchema;
```

After this I call it in app.js, on post method. The way it is written above it "works". But the errors that it throws are hardly readeble.

**My problem** is that the address have to be either an URL **or** an IP (ipv4) address. The way  I did it is wrong because that's an **and**. Is there a way to do it?

Another problem is the error handling. If I uncomment the *.error(new Error('...'))* it throws one error saying *AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: value must be a joi validation error*. On the internet I haven't found  a solution yet. What do you think? Is there a way to do this or I just have to do it "classically"?

Thank you very much!

Comment: try making 2 validate body schemas.. one for url, other for ipv4.. does that work?

Comment: yes bro, I fount the method! the idea is the one you said, but you can do it with the Joi. Check out my solution! and thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution!
From the https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0#alternativestryschemas you can find out how to do so:

```
address: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.string().uri(),Joi.string().ip)
```

Instead of checking if the address is a string you verify two options: if it's a string and it's an uri or if it's a string and it's an ipv4.